# How to recursively return a specific item from a tree model derived from QStandardItemModel?

Tags: python, qt, model-view-controller, recursion, pyqt

I am working on a Python-Qt app to help me learn MVC and OOP, but I am having some issues with recursive functions.

Using python2.7 and PyQt4:
I sub-classed QStandardItemModel and constructed a tree which is passed to QTreeView. Below is how I create the model.

The header is :

```
['Group Name','Has Files', 'File Count','Was Processed','Ancestors', 'Full Path']
```

## creating the model within the QStandardItemModel

```
def buildDirectoryTreeFromRootNode(self,rootDirectory):
    self.directoryTree = None
    self.directoryTree = self.createDirectoryTree(rootNode = rootDirectory, descendIntoSubdirs = self.recusiveFileSearch)
    self.buildTreeModel(self.directoryTree, parentItem = self)
```

## building the tree

```
def createDirectoryTree(self, rootNode, rootNodeDict=None, prevKeys=None,descendIntoSubdirs = True):
    # this function maps every folder below a root node into dict of form
    """
    @param rootNode: a valid directory
    @return dictionary like : {rootNode:{subDir1:{subSubDir1:{},subSubDir2:{}},subDir2:{}}
    """
    if rootNodeDict == None:
        rootNodeDict = dict()
        rootNodeDict[rootNode] = None
        rootNodeKey = rootNode
    else:
        rootNodeKey = split(rootNode)[-1]

    dirsInSubDir = getDirectorysAtNode(join(rootNode))

    if rootNodeDict[rootNodeKey] == None:
        rootNodeDict[rootNodeKey] = dict().fromkeys(dirsInSubDir)
    if prevKeys != None:
        if rootNodeKey in prevKeys:
            pass
        else:
            newPrevKeys = prevKeys
            newPrevKeys.append(rootNodeKey)
    elif prevKeys == None:
        newPrevKeys = []
        newPrevKeys.append(rootNodeKey)

    if descendIntoSubdirs == False:
        pass
    else:
        for subDir in dirsInSubDir:
            if '.' == subDir[0]:
                pass
            else:
                realDirID = join(rootNode, subDir)
                rootNodeDict[rootNodeKey][subDir] = dict()
                if rootNodeKey in newPrevKeys:
                    parentIndex = newPrevKeys.index(rootNodeKey) 
                    if parentIndex != len(newPrevKeys) - 1:
                        newPrevKeys = newPrevKeys[:parentIndex + 1] #this removes groups that have subdirs, so only terminal groups are processed
                rootNodeDict[rootNodeKey] = self.createDirectoryTree(rootNode=realDirID, rootNodeDict=rootNodeDict[rootNodeKey], prevKeys=newPrevKeys)
    return rootNodeDict
```

## creating model from tree dictonary

```
def buildTreeModel(self, dataDict, parentItem=None, prevKeys=None, depth=0):
    """
    @param prevKeys: a list of directory nodes from top to bottom
    @return None: appends QStandardItem model entrys to self which is  QStandardItemModel
    """
    for k, v in dataDict.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            groupKeyString = ''
            rootNodeKey = self.directoryTree.keys()[0].strip('/').split('/')[-1]
            try: 
                groupKeyString = k.strip('/').split('/')[-1]
            except:pass
            if groupKeyString == rootNodeKey:
                groupKey = groupKeyString
            else: 
                groupKey = k
            if prevKeys != None:
                newPrevKeys = prevKeys[:depth + 1]
                if groupKey in prevKeys:
                    pass
                else:
                    newPrevKeys.append(groupKey)
            elif prevKeys == None:
                newPrevKeys = self.directoryTree.keys()
            fullPathString = constructFilePathFromKeyList(newPrevKeys)
            fileList = getFilesAtNode(fullPathString, allowedExtensions=self.allowedExtensions)
            rootNode = QtGui.QStandardItem('%s' % groupKey)
            hasFilesBool = not len(fileList) ==0
            hasFiles = QtGui.QStandardItem('%s' %hasFilesBool)
            fileCountItem = QtGui.QStandardItem('%s' % len(fileList))
            wasProcessed = QtGui.QStandardItem('False')
            ancestors = QtGui.QStandardItem('%s' % depth)
            fullPathItem = QtGui.QStandardItem('%s' % fullPathString)
            rowList = [rootNode,hasFiles,fileCountItem, wasProcessed, ancestors, fullPathItem]
            [absItem.setEditable(False) for absItem in rowList]
            parentItem.appendRow(rowList)
            self.buildTreeModel(dataDict=v, parentItem=rootNode, prevKeys=newPrevKeys, depth=depth + 1)
```

So this works to create my tree model, but now I need to use the tree model to get access the 'Full Path' field of directorys which have not been processed but which do have files.

## Actual Query Model Function:

```
def getNextUnprocessedGroup(self,qTreeModelParentIndex=None):
    if qTreeModelParentIndex == None:
        qTreeModelParentIndex= self.index(0,0)
    else:
        qTreeModelParentIndex = qTreeModelParentIndex
    thisItem = self.itemFromIndex(qTreeModelParentIndex)
    rows = thisItem.rowCount()
    self.logger.info("parsing children of %s" %(qTreeModelParentIndex.data().toPyObject()))
    parentIndex = qTreeModelParentIndex.parent()
    self.groupNeedsProcessing(qTreeModelParentIndex)
    self.currentSelectedGroupItemIndex = qTreeModelParentIndex
    if rows == 0:
        return self.getNextUnprocessedGroup(parentIndex)
    else:
        for row in range(rows):
            treeIndex = self.index(row,self.nameIndex,qTreeModelParentIndex)
            hasFiles = self.index(row,self.hasFilesIndex,qTreeModelParentIndex).data().toPyObject()
            wasProcessed = self.index(row,self.wasProcessedIndex,qTreeModelParentIndex).data().toPyObject()
            fullPath = self.index(row,self.fullPathIndex,qTreeModelParentIndex).data().toPyObject()
            fullPath = str(fullPath)
            hasFiles = str2bool(hasFiles)
            wasProcessed = str2bool(wasProcessed) 
            thisItem = self.itemFromIndex(treeIndex)
            hasChildren = thisItem.hasChildren()
            needsProcessing = hasFiles and not wasProcessed

            if hasFiles and not wasProcessed:
                self.currentSelectedGroupItemIndex = treeIndex
                return fullPath
            else:
                if hasChildren:
                    return self.getNextUnprocessedGroup(treeIndex)
                elif parentIndex.isValid():
                    return self.getNextUnprocessedGroup(parentIndex)
```

So this function works to return the first value in the tree, but if I ask it for the next one it either returns None or gives me a recursion error. Any Idea what I'm doing wrong? I've tried lots of different things and still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured out what was wrong Here is the fixed function:

```
def getNextUnprocessedGroup(self,qTreeModelParentIndex=None):
    if qTreeModelParentIndex == None:
        qTreeModelParentIndex= self.index(0,0)
    else:
        qTreeModelParentIndex = qTreeModelParentIndex
    rootItem = self.itemFromIndex(qTreeModelParentIndex)
    rows = rootItem.rowCount()
    self.logger.info("parsing children of %s" %(qTreeModelParentIndex.data().toPyObject()))
    parentIndex = qTreeModelParentIndex.parent()
    self.currentSelectedGroupItemIndex = qTreeModelParentIndex
    if rows == 0:
        self.logger.debug( 'no children, trying parent')
        return self.getNextUnprocessedGroup(parentIndex)
    else:
        for row in range(rows):
            treeIndex = self.index(row,self.nameIndex,qTreeModelParentIndex)
            firstLabel = self.index(row,self.nameIndex,qTreeModelParentIndex).data().toPyObject()
            hasFiles = self.index(row,self.hasFilesIndex,qTreeModelParentIndex).data().toPyObject()
            wasProcessed = self.index(row,self.wasProcessedIndex,qTreeModelParentIndex).data().toPyObject()
            fullPath = self.index(row,self.fullPathIndex,qTreeModelParentIndex).data().toPyObject()
            fullPath = str(fullPath)
            hasFiles = str2bool(hasFiles)
            wasProcessed = str2bool(wasProcessed) 

            thisItem = self.itemFromIndex(treeIndex)
            hasChildren = thisItem.hasChildren()
            needsProcessing = hasFiles and not wasProcessed

            if needsProcessing:
                self.currentSelectedGroupItemIndex = treeIndex
                return fullPath
            elif hasChildren and not wasProcessed:
                return self.getNextUnprocessedGroup(treeIndex)
        self.groupWasProcessed(qTreeModelParentIndex)
        if parentIndex.isValid():
            return self.getNextUnprocessedGroup(parentIndex)
        else: return None
```

I think what the issue was is I was not properly handling what would happen after the for loop. I also fixed it so that if every subdir is processed but the node has no files, it will mark it as processed and skip that node in the future.

I'm sure this code could still be improved/simplified. Please let me know if anyone has any thoughts or opinions. I would greatly appreciate it as I am still learning as I go.